# NSE: Show Virtual Path instead of Filesystem Path in SaveAs (IFileSaveDialog) dialog

Tags: c#, windows-shell

That's the first time I'm posting something on StackOverflow. I'm desperately looking for a solution on a not really documented topic.

We have developped a DMS (FileSystem / Cloud services) solution integrated in Windows as a Namespace Extension. This solution works fine, The NSE is visible in IFileSaveDialog and we can directly save files in it.

My problem is that I would like to be able to show the virtual path, and not the filesystem path, when opening SaveAs dialog in applications such as Word, Excel, Notepad etc. (Used file was previously opened in the Namespace Extension).

I know that we could pass a IShellItem as argument in IFilSaveDialog.SetSaveAsItem, but would it have the desired effect (the given item has the attribute SFGAO_FILESYSTEM) and then, more difficult how could I possibly hook this when using SaveAs in a standard windows application?

Maybe I'm totally wrong and there is a very secret way of solving this (I even have tried to simulate drag and drop on applications such as Winword.exe, so I'm really stuck). But I'm sure (even if complicated), there is a solution, since Windows integrates virtual folders such as "My Documents" in SaveAs dialog.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the NSE is already registered under MyComputer, we can browse in it without any problems from this point, and we can recreate the virtual path without any problems. The NSE is working nicely, my only concern is to find a way to show the object in the Namespace Extension and not in the filesystem (temp or other location defined by us) when saving it.

Comment: did you find a solution ? I've the same problem. Tx.

Comment: Unfortunately not... The only workaround I've found is to develop an office Add-On

Comment: @gouigoui hi gouigoui, i wanted to ask how does you "save" work? it gives me "unspecified error" in case i'm trying to save in my virtual folder (it represents by real path)

Comment: @ArielB: Sorry for the late reply. I wasn't working on the namespace extension lately, so maybe my answer will not be that accurate. The problem I think is that you have to assume that the file you would like to save in your namespace extension already exists. When saving a file, you will need to retrieve all children in the virtual folder using their displaynames. If no virtual object is returned for your new file, then the "unspecified error" will occur. You just need to create a temporary virtual object for your new file.

Comment: hi, @gouigoui - I've managed to find it :) as i understood it gives me STGM_CREATE flag. 

other question though, is it possible that the ParseDisplayName will not be called after the first error? i'm facing another problem where i show error to the user (in message box) - but then another call is called, and the same error occurs - thus, he gets multiple message boxes.
i don't really want to cache the error and see if i should display it or not.
not sure if i managed to explain it correctly :)

Comment: @ArielB: I'm not sure I have understood your question. Can I assume that you've written your own implementation of IShellFolder.ParseDisplayName and/or IShellFolder2.ParseDisplayName and then handling STGM_CREATE in your implementation?

Comment: @ArielB: Guessing, the explorer will retrieve informations about NSE root, inner nodes, current virtual folder's children not only once as we "could" expect but several times.

Comment: @gouigoui yep, i've implemented it and i'm returning a virtual file upon the CREATE and then it works.  the several calls is a bit depressing, as it shows multiple message boxes, to solve it i would have to do something like "knowing i've already shown a message box, and to not show it again" , meh

Comment: @ArielB: Maybe you could serialize some vital (not too much) informations about your objects and then save it in memory... As Shell ID List? You would then avoid multiple message boxes. You will need to take care of objects validation and memory management.

Comment: @gouigoui you mean serialize the error along with the PIDL i'm guessing? 
yeah, it's a bit of a hassle, so i guess we will not handle it now...
thanks :)

Comment: @ArielB: No no, you shouldn't serialize the error... But you could serialize specs about your virtual object such as: "Is it a file or a folder", "what type of object is it", the object display name, some dates like date modified... the compulsory metadata you need to build your object without looking on filesystem, databases, files etc. Then you would avoid searching for children in your virtual folder several times throwing errors. Your error would be thrown only once, after your object would be directly deserialized and recreated... Maybe you should be more explicit about your error... :-)

Comment: well, i do have extra info, but when the method is called, i don't know that error already shown (it happens at the ParseDisplayName implementation) - i dont really know that last time i checked it error occured, so i need to save a state for it.

Comment: Hello @ArielB, how could I contact you? Have you got an email address? Best Regards

Comment: Yea, regarding this? Dm me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never answered back here. But eventually I found a solution.

Denis Anisimov was right when he was writing:

> If you see virtual folder in standard SaveAs dialog it only means that virtual folder has SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR attribute. Windows shows such folder but it waiting that folder contains objects with SFGAO_FILESYSTEM attribute.

On Windows 10 unfortunately, the folders must have both attributes. But that's not point.

So the answers is *"let the system think your object is a filesystem object and handle the file saving process yourself"*

So you shouldn't use a filesystem path for your object display name (otherwise you're done), then implement the Interface [IObjectWithSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693765(v=vs.85).aspx) in your virtual object's classes (Thank you ArielB for your posts!) and handle objects saving action yourself - in my case downloading the file in a temp folder and starting a Filesystemwatcher -.

I have posted some code excerpts. You will also need to develop your own IFileDialogEvents implementation.

```
    public NativeMethods.HRESULT GetSite(ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
    {
        if (PUnkSite != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.QueryInterface(PUnkSite, ref riid, out ppvSite);
            return NativeMethods.HRESULT.S_OK;
        }

        ppvSite = IntPtr.Zero;
        return NativeMethods.HRESULT.S_FALSE;
    }


    public void SetSite(IntPtr pUnkSite)
    {
        if (PUnkSite != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.Release(PUnkSite);

            if (FileSaveDialog != null)
            {
                FileSaveDialog.Unadvise(DwCookie);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(FileSaveDialog);
                FileSaveDialog = null;
                DwCookie = 0;
            }
            else if (FileOpenDialog != null)
            {
                FileOpenDialog.Unadvise(DwCookie);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(FileOpenDialog);
                FileOpenDialog = null;
                DwCookie = 0;
            }
        }

        PUnkSite = pUnkSite;
        if (PUnkSite == IntPtr.Zero) return;
        Marshal.AddRef(PUnkSite);

        Guid iFileSaveDialogGuid = typeof (NativeMethods.IFileSaveDialog).GUID;
        IntPtr iFileSaveDialogPointer;

        NativeMethods.IUnknown_QueryService(pUnkSite, ref NativeMethods.SID_SExplorerBrowserFrame, ref iFileSaveDialogGuid, out iFileSaveDialogPointer);

        if (iFileSaveDialogPointer != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            FileSaveDialog = (NativeMethods.IFileSaveDialog) Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(iFileSaveDialogPointer);

            Marshal.Release(iFileSaveDialogPointer);

            if (FileSaveDialog == null) return;

            FileDialogEvents dialogEvents = new FileDialogEvents(ConnectorName, FileDialogEvents.FileSaveType,
                ObjectMetadata.ObjectAddress, ObjectMetadata.ObjectClass);

            FileSaveDialog.Advise(dialogEvents, out DwCookie);
            return;
        }

        Guid iFileOpenDialogGuid = typeof(NativeMethods.IFileOpenDialog).GUID;
        IntPtr iFileOpenDialogPointer;

        NativeMethods.IUnknown_QueryService(pUnkSite, ref NativeMethods.SID_SExplorerBrowserFrame, ref iFileOpenDialogGuid, out iFileOpenDialogPointer);
        if (iFileOpenDialogPointer == IntPtr.Zero) return;

        FileOpenDialog = (NativeMethods.IFileOpenDialog)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(iFileOpenDialogPointer);

        Marshal.Release(iFileOpenDialogPointer);

        if (FileOpenDialog == null) return;

        FileDialogEvents dialogEventsOpen = new FileDialogEvents(ConnectorName, FileDialogEvents.FileOpenType,
            ObjectMetadata.ObjectAddress, ObjectMetadata.ObjectClass);

        FileOpenDialog.Advise(dialogEventsOpen, out DwCookie);
    }
```

Also here the COM objects (defined in NativeMethods):

```
    public static Guid SID_SExplorerBrowserFrame = new Guid("000214F1-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"); // SID_SExplorerBrowserFrame

    [ComImport, Guid("FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IObjectWithSite
    {
        void SetSite([In] IntPtr pUnkSite);

        HRESULT GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
    public struct COMDLG_FILTERSPEC
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pszName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pszSpec;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum FOS : uint
    {
        FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT = 0x00000002,
        FOS_STRICTFILETYPES = 0x00000004,
        FOS_NOCHANGEDIR = 0x00000008,
        FOS_PICKFOLDERS = 0x00000020,
        FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM = 0x00000040, // Ensure that items returned are filesystem items.
        FOS_ALLNONSTORAGEITEMS = 0x00000080, // Allow choosing items that have no storage.
        FOS_NOVALIDATE = 0x00000100,
        FOS_ALLOWMULTISELECT = 0x00000200,
        FOS_PATHMUSTEXIST = 0x00000800,
        FOS_FILEMUSTEXIST = 0x00001000,
        FOS_CREATEPROMPT = 0x00002000,
        FOS_SHAREAWARE = 0x00004000,
        FOS_NOREADONLYRETURN = 0x00008000,
        FOS_NOTESTFILECREATE = 0x00010000,
        FOS_HIDEMRUPLACES = 0x00020000,
        FOS_HIDEPINNEDPLACES = 0x00040000,
        FOS_NODEREFERENCELINKS = 0x00100000,
        FOS_DONTADDTORECENT = 0x02000000,
        FOS_FORCESHOWHIDDEN = 0x10000000,
        FOS_DEFAULTNOMINIMODE = 0x20000000
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum FDAP
    {
        FDAP_BOTTOM = 0,
        FDAP_TOP = 1
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("B63EA76D-1F85-456F-A19C-48159EFA858B"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IShellItemArray
    {
        // Not supported: IBindCtx
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void BindToHandler([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pbc, [In] ref Guid rbhid,
                     [In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvOut);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetPropertyStore([In] int Flags, [In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppv);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetPropertyDescriptionList([In] ref PROPERTYKEY keyType, [In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppv);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetAttributes([In] SIATTRIBFLAGS dwAttribFlags, [In] uint sfgaoMask, out uint psfgaoAttribs);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetCount(out uint pdwNumItems);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetItemAt([In] uint dwIndex, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        // Not supported: IEnumShellItems (will use GetCount and GetItemAt instead)
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void EnumItems([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IntPtr ppenumShellItems);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public struct PROPERTYKEY
    {
        public Guid fmtid;
        public uint pid;
    }

    public enum SIATTRIBFLAGS
    {
        SIATTRIBFLAGS_AND = 1,
        SIATTRIBFLAGS_APPCOMPAT = 3,
        SIATTRIBFLAGS_OR = 2
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IFileOpenDialog : IFileDialog
    {
        // Defined on IModalWindow - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), PreserveSig]
        int Show([In] IntPtr parent);

        // Defined on IFileDialog - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileTypes([In] uint cFileTypes, [In] COMDLG_FILTERSPEC[] rgFilterSpec);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileTypeIndex([In] uint iFileType);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFileTypeIndex(out uint piFileType);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Advise([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialogEvents pfde, out uint pdwCookie);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Unadvise([In] uint dwCookie);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetOptions([In] FOS fos);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetOptions(out FOS pfos);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetDefaultFolder([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFolder([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFolder([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetCurrentSelection([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileName([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFileName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pszName);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetTitle([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszTitle);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetOkButtonLabel([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszText);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileNameLabel([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszLabel);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetResult([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void AddPlace([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi, FDAP fdap);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetDefaultExtension([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDefaultExtension);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Close([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)] int hr);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetClientGuid([In] ref Guid guid);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void ClearClientData();

        // Not supported:  IShellItemFilter is not defined, converting to IntPtr
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFilter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pFilter);

        // Defined by IFileOpenDialog
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetResults([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItemArray ppenum);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetSelectedItems([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItemArray ppsai);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("84bccd23-5fde-4cdb-aea4-af64b83d78ab"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IFileSaveDialog : IFileDialog
    {
        // Defined on IModalWindow - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), PreserveSig]
        int Show([In] IntPtr parent);

        // Defined on IFileDialog - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileTypes([In] uint cFileTypes, [In] COMDLG_FILTERSPEC[] rgFilterSpec);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileTypeIndex([In] uint iFileType);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFileTypeIndex(out uint piFileType);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Advise([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialogEvents pfde, out uint pdwCookie);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Unadvise([In] uint dwCookie);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetOptions([In] FOS fos);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetOptions(out FOS pfos);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetDefaultFolder([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFolder([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFolder([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetCurrentSelection([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileName([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFileName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pszName);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetTitle([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszTitle);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetOkButtonLabel([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszText);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileNameLabel([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszLabel);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetResult([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void AddPlace([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi, FDAP fdap);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetDefaultExtension([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDefaultExtension);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Close([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)] int hr);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetClientGuid([In] ref Guid guid);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void ClearClientData();

        // Not supported:  IShellItemFilter is not defined, converting to IntPtr
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFilter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pFilter);

        // Defined by IFileSaveDialog interface
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetSaveAsItem([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi);

        // Not currently supported: IPropertyStore
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetProperties([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pStore);

        // Not currently supported: IPropertyDescriptionList
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetCollectedProperties([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pList, [In] int fAppendDefault);

        // Not currently supported: IPropertyStore
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetProperties([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IntPtr ppStore);

        // Not currently supported: IPropertyStore, IFileOperationProgressSink
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void ApplyProperties([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi,
                       [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pStore,
                       [In, ComAliasName("ShellObjects.wireHWND")] ref IntPtr hwnd,
                       [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pSink);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("42f85136-db7e-439c-85f1-e4075d135fc8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IFileDialog : IModalWindow
    {
        // Defined on IModalWindow - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), PreserveSig]
        int Show([In] IntPtr parent);

        // IFileDialog-Specific interface members
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileTypes([In] uint cFileTypes,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] COMDLG_FILTERSPEC[] rgFilterSpec);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileTypeIndex([In] uint iFileType);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFileTypeIndex(out uint piFileType);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Advise([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialogEvents pfde, out uint pdwCookie);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Unadvise([In] uint dwCookie);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetOptions([In] FOS fos);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetOptions(out FOS pfos);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetDefaultFolder([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFolder([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFolder([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetCurrentSelection([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileName([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetFileName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pszName);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetTitle([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszTitle);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetOkButtonLabel([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszText);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFileNameLabel([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszLabel);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetResult([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void AddPlace([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi, FDAP fdap);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetDefaultExtension([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDefaultExtension);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Close([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)] int hr);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetClientGuid([In] ref Guid guid);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void ClearClientData();

        // Not supported:  IShellItemFilter is not defined, converting to IntPtr
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetFilter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pFilter);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("b4db1657-70d7-485e-8e3e-6fcb5a5c1802"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IModalWindow
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), PreserveSig]
        int Show([In] IntPtr parent);
    }

    public enum HRESULT : long
    {
        S_FALSE = 0x0001,
        S_OK = 0x0000,
        E_INVALIDARG = 0x80070057,
        E_OUTOFMEMORY = 0x8007000E,
        STG_E_FILENOTFOUND = 0x80030002
    }

    public enum FDE_SHAREVIOLATION_RESPONSE
    {
        FDESVR_DEFAULT = 0x00000000,
        FDESVR_ACCEPT = 0x00000001,
        FDESVR_REFUSE = 0x00000002
    }

    public enum FDE_OVERWRITE_RESPONSE
    {
        FDEOR_DEFAULT = 0x00000000,
        FDEOR_ACCEPT = 0x00000001,
        FDEOR_REFUSE = 0x00000002
    }

    public enum Sigdn : uint
    {
        SigdnNormaldisplay = 0x00000000,
        SigdnParentrelativeparsing = 0x80018001,
        SigdnParentrelativeforaddressbar = 0x8001c001,
        SigdnDesktopabsoluteparsing = 0x80028000,
        SigdnParentrelativeediting = 0x80031001,
        SigdnDesktopabsoluteediting = 0x8004c000,
        SigdnFilesyspath = 0x80058000,
        SigdnUrl = 0x80068000
    }

    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
    public static extern int IUnknown_QueryService(IntPtr pUnk, ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvOut);

    [ComImport, Guid("973510DB-7D7F-452B-8975-74A85828D354"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IFileDialogEvents
    {
        // NOTE: some of these callbacks are cancelable - returning S_FALSE means that
        // the dialog should not proceed (e.g. with closing, changing folder); to
        // support this, we need to use the PreserveSig attribute to enable us to return
        // the proper HRESULT
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), PreserveSig]
        HRESULT OnFileOk([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialog pfd);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), PreserveSig]
        HRESULT OnFolderChanging([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialog pfd,
                       [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psiFolder);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void OnFolderChange([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialog pfd);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void OnSelectionChange([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialog pfd);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void OnShareViolation([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialog pfd,
                    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi,
                    out FDE_SHAREVIOLATION_RESPONSE pResponse);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void OnTypeChange([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialog pfd);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void OnOverwrite([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IFileDialog pfd,
                   [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi,
                   out FDE_OVERWRITE_RESPONSE pResponse);
    }

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int SHCreateItemFromIDList(
         /*PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE*/ IntPtr pidl,
    ref Guid riid,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard Windows application were developed for working with real files with using function like CreateFile. Such functions can not work with virtual files. If you see virtual folder in standard SaveAs dialog it only means that virtual folder has SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR attribute. Windows shows such folder but it waiting that folder contains objects with SFGAO_FILESYSTEM attribute. So I think that there is no any solution.

Comment: The "Containers" (folders) have the attribute SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR, but the files have SFGAO_FILESYSTEM. So I have a real filesystem path that represents the real data (When clicking on SaveAs, Windows Application will show the filesystem path, which is a bit "cryptic" for a user). The annoying thing is that, it will show the filesystem path, but the user will be able in the same SaveAs Window, to open the namespace Extension at the right place and then save the file there. These works fine.